# Directive attributes inside the raw html not working in Angular 8 application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I have raw html coming from api like this:

```
var data='<span mycustomdirective>Some text</span>';
```

I am appending this raw HTML in my div element like this

```
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

The text is binding fine but I can't see the attribute's(mycustomdirective) functionality working.
Whereas using this directive directly on static html is working properly.
Why I am facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

app.component.html

```
<div class="one" [innerHtml]="addData"></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

// declare like this 
    addData = '<div class="two">two</div>';
    
name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
    }
```

stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhwpd8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

you can use viewChild for inserting html tag ts to HTML page
firstly you have to import viewChild

> import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

```
<div class="demo" #demo></div>
@ViewChild('demo') d1:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="two">two</div>');
}
```

or you can use this

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

@ViewChild('demo') d1:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.d1.nativeElement', 'insertAdjacentHTML' ['beforeend', '<div class="demo2">demo2</div>']);
}

constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var d1 = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.demo');
  d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="demo2">demo2</div>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Piyush, my problem is a bit more complex than this one.

Comment: @Avinash Singh can you check my code again I hope it will help you